# Ошибка при подключении скрипта

Tags: javascript, jquery

При подключении скрипта консоль выдает такую ошибку:

```
 Object #<HTML Document> has no method 'ready'
```

В чем проблема?
`query` подключен.

Сам скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#test2").click(function(){
alert("rabotaet");
})
});
```

Comment: а jquery подключен?

Comment: да, я же написал

Comment: попробуйте:

    $(function(){
        $("#test2").click...
    });

Comment: так ошибку не выдает, но не работает

Comment: У вас кроме jquery какие-то библиотеки подключены использующие $?Prototype к примеру? 

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#test2").click(function(){
alert("rabotaet");
})
});

Так работать будет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему, кроме jQuery у вас подключена еще какая-то библиотека, использующая фукцию `$()` для выборки элементов страницы. Попробуйте отключить ее или обернуть код, использующий jQuery в функцию:

```
(function($){
    // ...
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вполне может быть, что у вас старая библиотека jquery. Попробуйте заменить на новую.